How do I solve Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure
I am writing integration test for  a project using TestContainers by following the tutorial [here][1] . I had a lot of errors which I managed to solve but couldn't not get pass the following errors.
caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:55101/test?loggerLevel=OFF

and
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:55101/test?loggerLevel=OFF

Here's my application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:13.6:///proforma?TC_DAEMON=true
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG


feign.autoconfiguration.jackson.enabled=true

feign.client.config.product.connect-timeout=5000
feign.client.config.product.read-timeout=5000
feign.client.config.product.logger-level=FULL

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.profiles.active = dev

My BaseRepository:
@DataJpaTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = BaseRepositoryTest.DataSourceInitializer.class)
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTest {
    @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> database = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres");
        public static class DataSourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{

        @Override
        public void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext){
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    "spring.test.database.replace=none", //tells springs not to start in-memory db for test
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + database.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + database.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + database.getPassword()
            );
        }
    }
}

RepositoryTest:
@DataJpaTest
@DisplayName("HistoryRepository test.")
class HistoryRepositoryTest extends BaseRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private  HistoryRepository historyRepository;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown(){
        historyRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    @Test
    void createHistory(){
        HistoryEntity historyEntity = new HistoryEntity();
        historyEntity.setMyEntity(new MyEntity());
        historyEntity.setEvent("test event");
        historyEntity.setLoggedUser("user");
        historyEntity.setVersion(1L);
        historyEntity.setEventDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        historyRepository.saveAndFlush(historyEntity);
        List<HistoryEntity> historyEntityList = historyRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, historyEntityList.size());
    }
}

I have searched for similar errors but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Where do you start the container?
Try this for starting the container:
public class TestContainerContext {

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER;

    static {
        POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(PostgreSQLContainer.IMAGE).withTag("15.1"));
        POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.setCommand("postgres", "-c", "max_connections=50000", "-c", "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=300s");
        POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }

    public static JdbcDatabaseContainer<?> getDbContainer() {
        return POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER;
    }

}

And then change your initialize to this:
@Override
public void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    TestPropertyValues.of(Map.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url", TestContainerContext.getDbContainer().getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.driver-class-name", TestContainerContext.getDbContainer().getDriverClassName(),
                    "spring.datasource.username", TestContainerContext.getDbContainer().getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password", TestContainerContext.getDbContainer().getPassword()))
            .applyTo(applicationContext);
}

